# How to remove an item from a collection without updating the view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Right now I'm firing this:

```
this.collection.remove(item);
```

Backbone.sync('update', this.collection, null);

It works great, but I'd like to be able to remove the item from the collection and sync without refreshing the html view (I've already removed the item from the page, using jQuery).  I know I could write jQuery to do this, but i'd like to keep it closer to the backbone functionality if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`silent`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove) option:

```
this.collection.remove(item, { silent: true });
```

This suppresses firing of the "remove" event, and so the view doesn't get notified.